# Flutter GlobalKey in forms - dispose after use?

Tags: flutter

I'm using GlobalKey objects in a Flutter form to support form validation and at a TextFormField level to support cross field validation.

Do these GlobalKey objects need to be released/disposed of when the form is disposed?

Answer (score 0):

In [Flutter Globalkey docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GlobalKey-class.html), Globalkey is explained that

> "They should usually be long-lived objects owned by a State object, Creating a new GlobalKey on every build will throw away the state of the subtree associated with the old key and create a new fresh subtree for the new key. Besides harming performance, this can also cause unexpected behavior in widgets in the subtree."

GlobalKey saved in Widget's state and if you generate global key for every each `build()` method, our application's performance is slow down.

In [Flutter dispose method docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/dispose.html),

> "This method is not invoked when the application shuts down, because there is no way to predict when that will happen. For example, a user's battery could catch fire, or the user could drop the device into a swimming pool, or the operating system could unilaterally terminate the application process due to memory pressure."

dispose method calls when application is shut down only.

So If you shut down app following disposed form widget, you might release globalkey. but If you do not shut down app following disposed form widget, globalkey is in Widget's state So you doesn't need release global key.